# Combining Powershell cmdlets issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I've pieced together a script (sorry can't remember the source), that returns multiple attributes using two cmdlets, (Get-user & Get-mailboxstatistics). The code works as expected if I specify an individual user but when using a wildcard to return all users it only returns the attributes from Get-user, and I don't know why.

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

```
    $outputCollection = @()
$users = Get-User -identity *
$mailboxes = Get-Mailboxstatistics -identity *

$users | Foreach-Object {
   #Associate objects
$userObject = $_
$mailboxObject = $mailboxes
$emailObject = $mail

#Make a combined object
$outputObject = "" | Select FirstName,Lastname,sAMAccountName,windowsemailaddress,ItemCount,Totalitemsize,TotalDeletedItemSize,DatabaseName,ServerName,LastLogonTime,LastLogoffTime
$outputObject.FirstName = $userObject.FirstName
$outputObject.Lastname = $userObject.Lastname
$outputObject.sAMAccountName = $userObject.sAMAccountName
$outputObject.windowsemailaddress = $userObject.windowsemailaddress   
$outputObject.itemcount = $mailboxObject.itemcount
$outputObject.Totalitemsize = $MailboxObject.Totalitemsize
$outputObject.TotalDeletedItemSize = $MailboxObject.TotalDeletedItemSize
$outputObject.DatabaseNAme = $mailboxObject.DatabaseName  
$outputObject.ServerName = $mailboxObject.ServerName  
$outputObject.lastlogontime = $mailboxObject.lastlogontime
$outputObject.lastlogofftime = $mailboxObject.lastlogofftime


  #Add the object to the collection
  $outputCollection += $outputObject
}

 $outputCollection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understand I changed as little as possible. For starters I would remove the `$mailboxes = Get-Mailboxstatistics -identity *` line. Then, for simplicity sake, update the line below

```
$mailboxObject = Get-Mailboxstatistics -identity $userObject.UserPrincipalName
```

You need to get the statistics for the *one* mailbox in each loop pass. Changing how you populate the `$mailboxObject` should accomplish that without the need to change anything else.

You can possibly remove `$emailObject = $mail` since you don't appear to be using it anywhere.

FYI This is not tested but should work. This also assumes that the user actually has an exchange mailbox. If not there will be null values in the output.

**About efficiency**

I wanted to try and make this simpler for you to understand. However note that what [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29752751/3829407) was trying to tell you about not running `Get-Mailboxstatistics` every time is true. My solution should still work though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've edited the code as you said but get the following error.                                                                                                      Get-MailboxStatistics : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configura
tion.Tasks.GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter". Error: "Parameter values of type Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Task
s.GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again.

Comment: Do you still have the line above with `$userObject = $_`? It sounds like `$userObject.UserPrincipalName` is returning null. If you just have the line `$userObject.UserPrincipalName` does it return the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that there's no correlation between `$users` and `$mailboxes`.

For example: Why would `$mailboxObject = $mailboxes` automatically pick the right user's mailbox?  The answer is that it wouldn't.  It would return *everything that was in `$mailboxes`*.  So `$mailboxObject.FirstName` doesn't mean anything, because `$mailboxObject` is an array, just like `$mailboxes` was.  You could say ``$mailboxObject[0].FirstName`, but that wouldn't correlate correctly.

You need a key field that exists in both objects that you can lookup with a `$mailboxObject = $mailboxes | Where-Object { $_.SomeKeyField = $userObject.SomeKeyField }` statement.

Alternately, you can wait to run `Get-MailboxStatistics` until you're inside your loop, but that will significantly increase the amount of traffic to your Exchange system.

Also, bear in mind that all the above assumes that a User exists for every MailboxStatistic.  If that's not the case, you'll have to do even more work if you want all of both in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this!

As mentioned by Bacon, either $users or $mailboxes should be filtered with a relationship between the two; Just like a Foreign Key.

**Always use Hash-Table when adding Key-Value pairs to have more options to manipulate and easy understanding

```
        # DECLARE HASHTABLE
        $outputCollection = @{}

        $users = Get-User -identity *
        $mailboxes = Get-Mailboxstatistics -identity $userObject.UserPrincipalName

        $users | Foreach-Object {
        #Associate objects
        $userCollection = $_
        $mailboxCollection = $mailboxes | Where-Object { $_.SomeKeyField = $userCollection.SomeKeyField }

        # ADD ELEMENTS TO HASH TABLE

        # Add elements from userCollection
        $outputCollection.add("FirstName",$userCollection.FirstName);
        $outputCollection.add("Lastname",$userCollection.Lastname);
        $outputCollection.add("sAMAccountName",$userCollection.sAMAccountName);
        $outputCollection.add("windowsemailaddress",$userCollection.windowsemailaddress);

        # Add elements from mailboxCollection
        $outputCollection.add("itemcount",$mailboxCollection.itemcount);
        $outputCollection.add("Totalitemsize",$mailboxCollection.Totalitemsize);
        $outputCollection.add("TotalDeletedItemSize",$mailboxCollection.TotalDeletedItemSize);
        $outputCollection.add("DatabaseNAme",$mailboxCollection.DatabaseNAme);
        $outputCollection.add("ServerName",$mailboxCollection.ServerName);
        $outputCollection.add("lastlogontime",$mailboxCollection.lastlogontime);
        $outputCollection.add("lastlogofftime",$mailboxCollection.lastlogofftime);
        }

        $outputCollection
```

By using Hash Table you could also be using different name for the Keys, Example you could do this,

```
       outputCollection.add("Last Logoff Time",$mailboxCollection.lastlogofftime);
       #Instead of
       outputCollection.add("lastlogofftime",$mailboxCollection.lastlogofftime);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using your code but get the error        Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Hashtable] doesn't contain a method named 'add_item'.   Also just wanted to check that                                                                           $outputCollection.add_item("FirstName",userCollection.FirstName);' should be                                                                    $outputCollection.add_item("FirstName",$userCollection.FirstName);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I finally managed to sort this using the following code.

```
Get-MailboxServer | Get-Mailbox -resultsize 1 | foreach-object {$email = $_.primarysmtpaddress; $_ | Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort @{expression= "totalitemsize";descending=$true}}| select DisplayName, @{expression={$_.totalitemsize.value.ToMB()};label=”Size(MB)”}, @{expression={$_.TotalDeletedItemSize.value.ToMB()};label=”Deleted Size(MB)”}, ServerName, DatabaseName, itemcount, lastlogontime, lastloggedonuseraccount, @{Name="EmailAddress";expression={$email}}| Export-csv c:\Report.csv -notypeinformation
```